# Copy folder keeping folder structure in target

Tags: linux, unix, copy, mkdir, cp

I have the folder `/var/test/abc/xyz/` and want to copy it to `/home/test/`.

Usually I do this with `cp -R /var/test/abc/xyz/ /home/test/` The problem is that `xyz/` gets copied directly into `/home/test`.

Is it possible that `abc/` will be created and `xyz/` gets copied into it, using `cp` or another copy-command directly?
I want to avoid the use of mkdir before, if it's possible.

Thanks for your help,
Lukas

Comment: You can do firstly `mkdir -p /home/test/var/test/abc/xyz/` so all directory structure will be created.

Comment: Hm ok I think I will do so. seems like there is no other possibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about `cp -R /var/test/abc/ /home/test/`? Assuming `abc` contains only `xyz`. If this is not the case, first create `abc/` in `test/` and then use your copy command.